# Stream.Read doesn't return received data

Tags: c#, stream, arrays

Here is the method I like to use. I believe, there is nothing new with this code.

```
 public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream stream, int initialLength)
    {
        // If we've been passed an unhelpful initial length, just
        // use 1K.
        if (initialLength < 1)
        {
            initialLength = 1024;
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[initialLength];
        int read = 0;

        int chunk;
        while ((chunk = stream.Read(buffer, read, buffer.Length - read)) > 0)
        {
            read += chunk;

            // If we've reached the end of our buffer, check to see if there's
            // any more information
            if (read == buffer.Length)
            {
                int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();

                // End of stream? If so, we're done
                if (nextByte == -1)
                {
                    return buffer;
                }

                // Nope. Resize the buffer, put in the byte we've just
                // read, and continue
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
                Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, buffer.Length);
                newBuffer[read] = (byte)nextByte;
                buffer = newBuffer;
                read++;
            }
        }
        // Buffer is now too big. Shrink it.
        byte[] ret = new byte[read];
        Array.Copy(buffer, ret, read);
        return ret;
    }
```

My goal is to read data sent from TCP Clients e.g. `box{"id":1,"aid":1}`
It is a command to interpret in my application in Jason-like text.
And this text is not necessarily at the same size each time.
Next time there can be `run{"id":1,"aid":1,"opt":1}`.

The method called by this line;

```
var serializedMessageBytes = ReadFully(_receiveMemoryStream, 1024);
```

[Please click to see; Received data in receiveMemoryStream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qgtj.png)
Although we can see the data in the stream,
in the `ReadFully` method, "chunck" always return `0` and the method returns `{byte[0]}`.

Any help effort greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use `stream.CopyTo(memoryStream)` and then `memoryStream.ToArray()`?

Comment: Because of the buffer?

Comment: Under the hood, stream default buffer size is `DefaultCopyBufferSize = 81920;`

Comment: Jeoren; thanks for your input. You are actually right about it.

Comment: Jeoren's comment may save my day. It is returning a byte array with the data I expect. But, the idea was using that method to handle larger data, random in size. And then you can consume the data in chunks in order to avoid out of memory or any other IO issues. If this is the case and I still want to use that method for future expansions, what is wrong with the "Stream.Read" then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your stream in the Watch window, the Position of the stream (19) is at the end of the data, hence there is nothing left to read.  This is possibly because you have just written data to the stream and have not subsequently reset the position.

Add a `stream.Position = 0;` or `stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);` statement at the start of the function if you are happy to always read from the start of the stream, or check the code that populates the stream.  Note though that some stream implementations do not support seeking.

Comment: Jackson, good catch. Once I rewind the position to 0, it has just started to work. In fact that, there is a reset for this before calling the method. `_receiveMemoryStream.Position = 0;`. But, between this reset and method call, there was some another calls using the stream and most likely they leave the position at the end of the array again. So, happy ending. Thank you.